# Adjustable power supply from +5V to -5V

Tags: power-supply, class-ab

Depending on the orientation of a nulling coil I need an adjustable voltage supply from ~+5V to -5V upto ~200mA. I've tried a few circuits similar to Class AB amplifiers such as the one shown below, but these normally expect an AC coupled input. Has anybody got any other suggestions?
[image: Class AB amp from www.electronics-tutorials.ws]

Comment: for a one-off lab application at 200mA x 10V, you can go with class A and a heat sink... i.e. simply an OPA with a BJT or MOS follower and a resitive minimum load

Comment: but wait, what are the available voltage rails from which you want to *feed* your adjustable supply?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider a unipolar to bipolar level shifting circuit that is based on a power op amp. An example schematic is shown below. Instead of the DAC, you could simply use a potentiometer.

Regarding calculations, there is a good application note [here](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/app-notes/5/5581.html), which should help you hit the ground running.

Keep in mind that you will need to ensure that the op amp can source/sink the necessary load current.

[image]

Comment: The app note you recommended is very good and inspiring: APPLICATION NOTE 5581 CHALLENGE THE CONVENTIONAL - MAKE UNIPOLAR DACS BIPOLAR By: Yuriy Kurtsevoy - Maxim Integrated, 2015
https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/app-notes/5/5581.html. Thank you very much. Cheers.